# Finding Euclidean distance between two list

Tags: python, list

```py
list1=[(1116.7983351235232, 1311.3754027926993), (1116.7983351235232, 1218.42998120301), (1116.7983351235232, 1125.4845596133205), (1116.7983351235232, 1032.539138023631), (1116.7983351235232, 939.5937164339416)]

list2=[(1215.7983351235232, 1315.130773361976), (1215.7983351235232, 1223.1241944146077), (1215.7983351235232, 1131.1176154672394), (1215.7983351235232, 1039.111036519871), (1215.7983351235232, 947.1044575725027)]
```

For the above list, I want to find the Euclidean distance between a point in `list1` and all the points in `list2`.
Here, I want to find the min distance from the point in list1 to all the points in list2.
Could any one suggest what is the best way to work on it?

i tried out

```
for i in list1:
     for j in list2:
         list3=min(sqrt(i,j))  
            print(list3)
```

I am getting error as
  AttributeError: 'Tuple' object has no attribute '_eval_power'

Comment: please add details about: your desired goal, expected and actual results of your code + error messages. Describe, what you have tried and show your code.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: You can't just call `sqrt` with two tuples and expect it to work. What would `sqrt((1, 2), (3, 4))` even mean?

Answer (score 0):

I propose doing this step by step:

First, write a function that calculates the euclidean distance between two points. We can do this by using Pythagoras' theorem on the *distance* between their respective components:

[image]

```
from math import sqrt

def distance(x, y):
    a, b = y[0] - x[0], y[1] - x[1]
    return sqrt(a**2 + b**2)
```

Now you can loop over all combinations of points and return all distances. I'll use a generator to do that:

```
def all_distances(one, two):
    for point_a in one:
        for point_b in two:
            yield distance(point_a, point_b)
```

Finally, it all falls into place:

```
>>> min(all_distances(list1, list2))
99.07120069986327
```

So the minimum distance is (very close to) 99.

Comment: Thanks you, Instead of yield can i return the function.

Comment: Why would you want to return the function?